# How to create package file for packages

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am trying for offline installation of certain packages using apt-get. I have modified sources.list file to reflect the local cache directory path where I have kept all the required packages. However, when I do apt-get install of the package(which is present in local cache direcory), I get error "Package" file not found. How do I create the package file?

When I run apt-get install vim, I get "Package" fiel not found though vim_xxxx.deb package is present in local cache direcory

Note: I also copied Package file from ubuntu archive repository into the local cache direcory and installation went fine. Is this the correct solution? OR should I create a new Package file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following command and it worked

sudo dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -c9 > Packages.gz

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .deb file you can easily install it by right clicking on it and selecting Gdebi install. If you want to go through command line after going to directory of the package, type

> sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME

this will install it with Gdebi which is similar to apt-get.

(if you aren't sure about directory just right click on your file and select open in terminal.)